# How do I hijack an Atlas?

Tags: mass-effect-3

How do I hijack an Atlas?
I have managed to shatter the cockpit glass but I do not see any option to hijack it when I get in close and it blows if I kill the pilot.

Comment: I'll note that you *can't* hijack the first Atlas in the Grissom Academy level! You can only hijack the ones in the last area, after you're given the empty atlas to steal. Spent over an hour trying. If you kill the pilot in the early atlases, the Atlas blows up, ALWAYS. Extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it blows up you damaged the Atlas too much. You need to both shatter the cockpit and kill the pilot, you'll see no prompt to hijack it before you kill the pilot.

I'd try to kill the pilot with a lower damage weapon, to avoid blowing up the mech at that point. An upgraded high-damage sniper rifle might deal to much damage at once for this to work.

Comment: I've unloaded 9 Black Widow X shots to an unshielded Atlas cockpit on Insanity and it didn't break. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Ok, 5 shots with the Widox X, the most powerful sniper rifle in the game - still no luck. Do I need to shoot precisely at the pilot's head?

Comment: @Kotekzot you have to get rid of the shields first, and then fire a few shots at the glowing dome where the pilot sits.

Comment: @yx. That's what I was doing without success.

Comment: I managed to do this but the Atlas ended up being in poor condition and blew up after being hit a few times.

Comment: The best way to keep the Atlas in good shape is when a Cerberus engineer is near. When the mech's shields are gone, just shoot the glass of the cockpit and wait for the repairs.

Answer (score 3):

I found that with 3 shots with the black widow V with pierce IV and extended barrel IV while under adrenaline rush will kill the pilot and shatter the glass and only drop about 1/12th of the mechs health. (this is all after the shields have been dropped)

Comment: pretty sure you don't need the pierce mod since the black widow has inherent piercing properties

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Graal Spike Thrower V.  Make sure you aim for the cockpit.  I shot it about 4 times after the shields were down.